# show textbox after definition in code

Tags: c#, textbox, show

Say I define an array of textboxes this way:

```
TextBox[] myTextBoxes = new TextBox[10];
```

How do I get them to show on the design window? I suppose the same method applies for labels, buttons, etc.

Comment: You've also not actually created any `TextBox`es, only an array of the specified size to hold them...

Answer (score 3):

Only components created in the designer, which are placed in the designer.cs file and executed by the InitializeComponent method are shown in the designer. If you create your own components and add them manually, they will be only shown at runtime.

Comment: @Fuex did that really need rolled back?

Answer (score 0):

You can't show them in the design window because they are created at runtime, while design window is shown at.. Desing time? :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to see it in the designer. Assuming this is WPF, to get the TextBox to even render you would at least need to add the control to a `Panel`.